# Why is my hitTest in UIView not identifying CALayer touched

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, calayer

I have a UIView in which 2 CALayers are added `[self.layer addSublayer:subLayerA]; //...` giving the following view hierarchy:

```
UIView subclass
 - backing layer (provided by UIView)
    - subLayerA
    - subLayerB
```

If I override `touchesBegan` in a ***view controller*** that presents the UIView it *correctly* identifies the CALayer touched:

```
// in view controller

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
//.....

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        CALayer *touchedLayer = [self.view.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchPoint];  // returns a copy of touchedLayer
        CALayer *actualLayer = [touchedLayer modelLayer];  // returns the actual CALayer touched
        NSLog (@"touchPoint: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
        NSLog (@"touchedLayer: %@", touchedLayer);
        NSLog (@"actualLayer: %@", actualLayer);
}
```

*However*, if I override `touchesBegan` in the ***UIView*** whose backing layer is the parent of the two sublayers, it will return `null` for the CALayer (though gives the correct touchPoint):

```
// in UIView subclass

#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
//.....

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CALayer *touchedLayer = [self.layer.presentationLayer hitTest:touchPoint];  // returns a copy of touchedLayer
    CALayer *actualLayer = [touchedLayer modelLayer];  // returns the actual CALayer touched
    NSLog (@"touchPoint: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchPoint));
    NSLog (@"touchedLayer: %@", touchedLayer);
    NSLog (@"actualLayer: %@", actualLayer);
}
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: you are referencing `layer`'s presentation model, which could be nil unless you have some animation going on. replace `self.view.layer.presentationLayer` with `self.view.layer` or add an if statement with nil checks

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem..

CALayer's hitTest method requires the location in the coordinates of the receiver's super layer.

So adding the following line should fix it:
touchPoint = [self.layer  convertPoint: touchPoint  toLayer: self.layer.superlayer]

This would explain why the test [subLayerA hitTest:touchPoint] works (touchPoint is in the coordinate space for "self", which is the parent of subLayerA)

Hope that helps.

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/hitTest:

Comment: This is such a no brainer and makes total sense. A+. I'd buy you a beer if I could.

Answer (score 0):

I am still unsure why my original code in the UIView subclass did not work.  As a workaround, I was able to individually test hitView on each layer of interest.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    //check if subLayerA touched
    if ([subLayerA hitTest:touchPoint]) {
        // if not nil, then subLayerA hit
        NSLog(@"subLayerA hit");
    }
    //check if subLayerB touched
    if ([self.subLayerB hitTest:touchPoint]) {
        // if not nil, then subLayerB hit
        NSLog(@"subLayerB hit");
}
```

I won't mark this as correct yet, as I technically haven't answered why my original code did not work - and someone yet may have the answer.

Comment: since this one works for you i guess your problem was using `presentationLayer` for hit testing maybe?